# Windows - Apache HTTP server - access to other directories on local FS

Tags: apache

I have a Windows 7 laptop with an installation of the Apache HTTP server (just for development purposes, not accessible from outside).

My problem is that I have my web applications located in two different directories on two different HD partitions.

How do I configure Apache to be able to launch applications from both locations?

I tried configuring one of them as the document root and pointing to the other one with a hard-link (but hard-links cannot point to folders) or sym-link (but Apache does not seem to understand Windows sym-links).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are they two separate applications? If so, you can create two named virtual hosts, one will point to the firts app, the other to the second. Then you just need to edit your "hosts" file to create the two names.

See any tutorial on vhosts, e.g. http://apptools.com/phptools/virtualhost.php

Comment: This seems to solve my problem (even though it is not exactly what I was looking for - e.g. to have applications from both locations under the localhost domain). Thanks!